# How to visualize mass properties with the RobotModel plugin (rviz2)?

Tags: rviz, plugin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to visualize in `rviz` the mass properties of a robot simulation. This properties are in the `inertial` block in the `urdf` of each part of the robot. According to [this](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz/issues/1204) and [this](https://github.com/ros2/rviz/pull/714) threads, this should be implemented, and it is a matter of configuring the `RobotModel` plugin, so does anybody knows how to do this?

I'm currently using `ros2` in foxy.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/389935/how-to-visualize-mass-properties-with-the-robotmodel-plugin-(rviz2)?/) by [jasr](https://answers.ros.org/users/87553/jasr/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2021-11-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-11-03**:
Is this a duplicate of #q388944?

It actually has a better title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You tagged this `foxy`, and that's likely why you can't find the checkbox (which you mention in the comments you posted on [ros2/rviz#714](https://github.com/ros2/rviz/pull/714)).

Unfortunately the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/ros2/rviz/blob/afebc17338b6e5d3d608d1c3b2c23e666862e70e/rviz2/CHANGELOG.rst) does not seem to make any mention of that PR, nor the feature, but as you can see in [ros2/rviz@2b551f80](https://github.com/ros2/rviz/commit/2b551f808e8e8c9bd29bc006d06a549c00db4861), this feature was merged into RViz2 version `8.7.0`:

[image: PR merge commit]

According to [index.ros.org/p/rviz2](https://index.ros.org/p/rviz2/#foxy) (and [status_page/ros_foxy_default.html?q=rviz2](http://repo.ros2.org/status_page/ros_foxy_default.html?q=rviz2)), RViz2 is at version `8.2.x` in Foxy.

The only ROS 2 version which has RViz2 at `8.7.0` would be Rolling at this time. See [index.ros.org/p/rviz2/#rolling](https://index.ros.org/p/rviz2/#rolling).

Galactic gets `8.5.0` ([index.ros.org/p/rviz2/#galactic](https://index.ros.org/p/rviz2/#galactic)).

So that would explain why you don't have that checkbox.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jasr](https://answers.ros.org/users/87553/jasr/) on 2021-11-04**:
Thank you very much for the answer, now I understand what's happening. Do you think there's a way to make this work in foxy? I'm thinking maybe modifying the files with the changes listed in the commit can work, but I can't find in my local foxy files all the files listed in the commit, I can see the .hpp, but the .cpp I don't know where they are. Any suggestions? Really appreciate your help, thanks again!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2021-11-05**:
You could try and see whether you can build Rolling's RViz2 on Foxy, but there are no guarantees it will work.

Failing that, you could try to backport the changes from just the PR to a Foxy source checkout of RViz2 in a Colcon workspace.

**Comment by [jasr](https://answers.ros.org/users/87553/jasr/) on 2021-11-05**:
Got it, thanks again for your help!